# Push-API still not supported in Safari 16 (Technology Preview)?

Tags: safari, web-push, push-api

We want to test if our implementation of web-push notifications will run in Safari 16 as well. So we downloaded the "Safari Technology Preview" 148 from https://developer.apple.com/safari/resources/ to test our implementation of Web-Pushs on macOS Monterey 12.4.

We use this code to detect if a browser supports Web-Pushes:

```
function WebPushSupported()
{   if (!window.Notification)
    {   return false;
    }
    
    if (!('serviceWorker' in navigator))
    {   return false;
    }
    
    if (!('PushManager' in window))
    {   return false;
    }   

    return true;
}
```

This works fine in Chrome, Firefox and so on, but Safari 16 has no object "PushManager" in window.

Are WebPushes through the Push-API still not supported in Safari 16?

Comment: The following link states that it is partially supported

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PushManager

Comment: Thank you! I still can't figure out what "partially supported" means, because either I do have a PushManager-object or I don't...

Comment: Hi, I just stumbled on this Apple developer documentation. It details some onerous steps plus the proper JS to test for push capabilities in Safari `'safari' in window && 'pushNotification' in window.safari` : https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/NotificationProgrammingGuideForWebsites/PushNotifications/PushNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013225-CH3-SW8

Comment: Din anyone managed to make push API notifications in Safari 16 work? I tried firebase messaging web v9 and it seem to work in background (when delivered by the service worker) but in foreground only receives notifications 3 times, then it stops working.